# Unpivot a table in C#

Tags: c#

I'm building a function in C# to unpivot a complex table in a CSV file and insert it into a SQL table.  The file looks something like this:

```
             | 1/5/2018 | 1/5/2018 | 1/6/2018 | 1/6/2018...
City:        | min:     | max:     | min:     | max:
Boston(KBOS) | 1        | 10       |  5       | 12
```

My goal is to unpivot it like so:

```
airport_code | localtime | MinTemp | MaxTemp
KBOS         | 1/5/2018  | 1       | 10
KBOS         | 1/6/2018  | 5       | 12
```

My strategy is:

1. Store the first row of dates and the second row of headers into arrays
2. Use a CSV parser to read each following line and loop through each field
3. If the date that corresponds to the current field is same as the previous one, it's belongs in the same row.  Put the data into the appropriate field. 
   Since there are only two temperature fields for each row, this row is complete can now be inserted.
4. Otherwise, start a new row and put the data into the appropriate field.

However, I'm running into a problem:  Once insertRow is populated and inserted, I can't overwrite it or null all the fields and use it again - that throws an error that row has already been inserted.  I can't move the declaration of insertRow inside the for loop because I need to preserve the data through multiple iterations to completely fill out the row.  So instead I tried to declare it outside the loop but only initialize it inside the loop, something like:

```
if(insertRow == null)
{
    insertRow = MyDataSet.tblForecast.NewtblForecastRow();
}
```

But that throws a "use of unassigned local variable" error.  Any ideas about how I can preserve insertRow on some iterations and dispose of it on others?  Or, any suggestions about a better way to do what I'm looking for?  The relevant portion of the code is below:

```
using (TextFieldParser csvParser = new TextFieldParser(FileName))
{
    csvParser.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });

    csvParser.ReadLine(); //Skip top line
    string[] dateList = csvParser.ReadFields();//Get dates from second line. 
    string[] fieldNames = csvParser.ReadFields();//Get headers from third line

    //Read through file
    while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
    {
        DataSet1.tblForecastRow insertRow = MyDataSet.tblForecast.NewtblForecastRow();
        string[] currRec = csvParser.ReadFields();

        //Get airport code
        string airportCode = currRec[0].Substring(currRec[0].LastIndexOf("(") + 1, 4);

        //Unpivot record
        DateTime currDate = DateTime.Parse("1/1/1900");//initialize
        DateTime prevDate;

        for (int i = 1; i<fieldNames.Length; i++) //skip first col
        {
            prevDate = currDate;//previous date is the prior current date
            DateTime.TryParse(dateList[i], out currDate);//set new current date

            int val;
            int.TryParse(currRec[i], out val);
            switch (fieldNames[i].ToLower())
            {
                case "min:":
                    insertRow["MinTemp"] = val;
                    break;
                case "max:":
                    insertRow["MaxTemp"] = val;
                    break;
            }

            if (currDate == prevDate)//if same date, at end of row, insert
            {
                insertRow["airport_code"] = airportCode;
                insertRow["localTime"] = currDate;
                insertRow["Forecasted_date"] = DateTime.Today;
                MyDataSet.tblForecast.AddtblForecastRow(insertRow);
                ForecastTableAdapter.Update(MyDataSet.tblForecast);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: add a class with five member variables airport_code, localTime, Forecasted_date, MinTemp and MaxTemp. populate an instance of it instead of the insertRow. in the last if, where the data is added, declare and create the insertRow, populate it from the instance of the class, and add it to the datatable.

Answer (score 1):

You create a new row when you finished handling the current one. And you already know where that is:

```
if (currDate == prevDate)//if same date, at end of row, insert
{
    insertRow["airport_code"] = airportCode;
    insertRow["localTime"] = currDate;
    insertRow["Forecasted_date"] = DateTime.Today;
    // we're storing insertRow
    MyDataSet.tblForecast.AddtblForecastRow(insertRow);
    // now it gets saved (man that is often)
    ForecastTableAdapter.Update(MyDataSet.tblForecast);

    // OKAY, let's create the new insertRow instance
    insertRow = MyDataSet.tblForecast.NewtblForecastRow();
    // and now on the next time we end up in this if 
    // the row we just created will be inserted
}
```

Your initial Row can be created outside the loop:

```
// first row creation
DataSet1.tblForecastRow insertRow = MyDataSet.tblForecast.NewtblForecastRow();
//Read through file
while (!csvParser.EndOfData)
{
    // line moved out of the while loop
    string[] currRec = csvParser.ReadFields();
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks!  And yes, I know I'm updating way too frequently :) I just have that there while I'm testing so I can see each row appear in SQL as it goes in.